# Expression is not assignable. C++ for loop (initialisations, conditions, updates)

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements, codeblocks

I am trying to create code that satisfies 3 conditions:

1) x , y, z are positive integers less than 1000
2) x is always less than y
3) x^2 + y^2 = z^2

Below is my code with a "for" loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int x, y,z,i;
    for(x=1,y=1,z=1,i=0;x<1000,y<1000,z<1000, x<y, x*x + y*y = z*z;x++,y++,z++)
    {

          cout << "x= " << x << "y= " << y << "z= " << z << endl;

        i++;
    }
    cout << "There are " << i << "(x,y,z) triples satisfying x^2 + y^2 = z^2" ;
    return 0;
}
```

The errors that I was given were:
1. error:expression is not assignable
2. relational comparison result unused
3. expression result unused.

May I know what's wrong with my code?

---

Suppose I use `&&` instead of `,` so as to satisfy the 3 conditions and proceed with using 3 nested loops, what would the logic be like?

Thank you guys.
I made a change to my code to include the 3 nested loop however the number of triples i can find seems to be wrong as what would be expected.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int counter = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x != 1000; ++x, ++counter)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y != 1000; ++y)
                {
                    for (int z = 1; z != 1000; ++z)
                        {
                            if (x*x+y*y==z*z && x<y)
                            cout << "x=" << x << " y=" << y << " z=" << z<<  endl;
                    }
            }

    }

    cout << "There are " << counter << " (x, y, z) triples satisfying x^2 + y^2 = z^2";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the initialisation? Ans : 878, My ans: 999

Comment: Are you sure this will form a valid condition expression: `x<1000,y<1000,z<1000, x<y, x*x + y*y = z*z;`?? Did you mean `x<1000 && y<1000 && z<1000 && x<y && x*x + y*y == z*z;`

Comment: The expression `x*x + y*y = z*z` is indeed not a valid assignment. Do you perhaps mean to check for equality using `==`?

Comment: You're looking for `&&` in your condition, not `,`.

Comment: And you'll need three nested for loops.

Comment: x=1,y=1,z=1,i=0;x<1000 && y<1000 && z<1000 && x<y && x*x + y*y == z*z;x++,y++,z++ got it changed to this

Comment: No way this code passes code review in my organisation. Can't you write it in a clear and self-documenting fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Three for loops look like

```
for (int x = 1; x != 1000; ++x)
{
   for (int y = 1; y != 1000; ++y)
   {
       for (int z = 1; z != 1000; ++z)
       {
          if (some_condition)
             ++counter;
       }
   }
}
```

You might improve on this by not running all the variables up to 1000, as you know that `x < y` and both `x` and `y` must be smaller than `z`. Maybe a lot smaller.

---

In addition to the compile errors, your single loop has the problem that is increments `x`, `y`, and `z` in sync, so you will just check (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3), etc. This will never satisfy the third condition.

Answer (score 0):

Reinsert the code into the loop. I don't know why but it works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int counter = 0;
for (int x = 1; x != 1000; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y != 1000; ++y)
            {
                for (int z = 1; z != 1000; ++z)
                    {
                        if (x*x+y*y==z*z && x<y)
                          {
                              counter++;
                              cout << "x=" << x << " y=" << y << " z=" << z<< endl;
                          }
                    }
            }

    }

    cout << "There are " << counter << " (x, y, z) triples satisfying x^2 + y^2 = z^2";

    return 0;
}
```